# Using namespaces in C++?

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code? It says func1 and func2 is not declared. I've tried declaring it using "using namespace func1::print()" but I still receive this error?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
func1::print();
func2::print();
return 0;
}

namespace func1 {
void print() {
    cout<<"HELLO WORLD";
}
}

namespace func2 {
void print() {
    cout<<"HELLO";
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the namespaces it is that they are after `int main()`.

Comment: You must declare a function *before* calling it

Answer (score 0):

Simply reorder your code, as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace func1 {
    void print() {
        cout << "HELLO WORLD";
    }
}

namespace func2 {
    void print() {
        cout << "HELLO";
    }
}

int main() {
    func1::print();
    func2::print();
    return 0;
}
```

This way, your two `namespace` and `print` functions have been declared and defined by the time they are used in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the function definition before your main, or a function declaration which tells the compiler that the function exists *somewhere*.  It will look for the actual definition later on, and will complain if it doesn't find it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace func1 {
    void print();
}
namespace func2 {
    void print();
}

int main() {
    func1::print();
    func2::print();
    return 0;
}

namespace func1 {
    void print() {
        cout<<"HELLO WORLD";
    }
}

namespace func2 {
    void print() {
        cout<<"HELLO";
    }
}
```